# Rename various rows

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[Starting Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvJ2o.png)

Code used to create the Starting dataset:

```
dataset<-data.frame(Attorney=c("John Doe", "Client #1","274", "296",
                           "297", "Client #2", "633", "Jane Doe",
                           "Client #1", "309", "323"),
                Date=c(NA, NA, "2019/4/4", "2019/4/4", "2019/4/12",
                       NA, " 2019/2/3", NA, NA, "2019/12/1", "2019/12/4"),
                Code=c(NA, NA, "7NP/7NP", "1UE/1UE", "2C1/2C1",NA,
                       "7NP/7NP", NA, NA, "7NP/7NP", "7FU/7FU"),
                Billed_Amount=c(NA, NA, 1200.00, 4000.00, 2775.00,
                               NA, 1200.00, NA, NA, 1200.00, 385),
                Amount= c(NA, NA, "1200", "4000", "2775", NA, "1200",
                          NA, NA, "1200", "385"),
                Current =c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0),
                X.120=c(NA, NA, "1200", "4000", "2775", NA, "1200",
                        NA, NA, "1200", "385"))
```

My goal is to end up with a dataset that looks like:

[Goal Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZshiJ.png)

Code used to create Goal dataset:

```
dataset<-data.frame(Attorney=c("John Doe", "John Doe", "John Doe", 
                           "John Doe", "Jane Jane", "Jane Jane"),
                Date=c("2019/4/4", "2019/4/4", "2019/12/4", " 2019/2/3",
                       "2019/12/1","2019/12/4" ),
                Code=c("7NP/7NP", "1UE/1UE","2C1/2C1", "7NP/7NP",
                       "7NP/7NP", "7FU/7FU"),
                Billed_Amount=c(1200.00, 4000.00,2775.00, 1200.00,
                                1200.00, 385),
                Amount= c(1200, 4000, 2775, 1200,1200, 385),
                Current= c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                X.120=c(1200, 4000, 2775,1200, 1200, 385))
```

I want to rename the rows underneath each attorney with the attorney's name while not worrying about preserving the client's name. My original dataset has a number of attorneys and they have a varying number of clients and those clients have a various number of codes, dates, and amounts associated with them.

I tried to use if else statement but encountered an error message.

I appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks!

Edit: I have edited my question to include hypothetical attorney names.

Comment: Please provide a clear title to your question. Also, make a minimum working example. Thanks.

Comment: Saying you encountered an error message without saying what the error is and what the code is that produces the error is a good indicator of a [bad question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create a grouping variable based on the presence of 'Attorney substring in 'Attorney' column, then `mutate` the 'Attorney' column with the `first` element of 'Attorney' after grouping by 'grp', `filter` out the `NA` elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dataset %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Attorney, "^Attorney"))) %>% 
   mutate(Attorney = first(Attorney)) %>% 
   filter_at(vars(Date:X.120), all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-grp)
```

---

We can also use `na.omit` here

```
dataset %>%
     group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Attorney, "^Attorney"))) %>% 
     mutate(Attorney = first(Attorney)) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     select(-grp) %>%
     na.omit
# A tibble: 6 x 7
#  Attorney    Date        Code    Billed_Amount Amount Current X.120
#  <fct>       <fct>       <fct>           <dbl> <fct>    <dbl> <fct>
#1 Attorney #1 "2019/4/4"  7NP/7NP          1200 1200         0 1200 
#2 Attorney #1 "2019/4/4"  1UE/1UE          4000 4000         0 4000 
#3 Attorney #1 "2019/4/12" 2C1/2C1          2775 2775         0 2775 
#4 Attorney #1 " 2019/2/3" 7NP/7NP          1200 1200         0 1200 
#5 Attorney #2 "2019/12/1" 7NP/7NP          1200 1200         0 1200 
#6 Attorney #2 "2019/12/4" 7FU/7FU           385 385          0 385
```

---

Or another option is to `fill` the 'Attorney' column after `replace`ing the non 'Attorney' substring elements with `NA` so that it gets filled with the previous non-NA element, then do `na.omit`

```
library(tidyr)
dataset %>%
  mutate(Attorney = replace(Attorney, !str_detect(Attorney, "Attorney"), NA)) %>% 
  fill(Attorney) %>%
  na.omit
```

Comment: Thank You for the solution.  I edited my original question a bit to include attorney names and I tried to adapt your code to my original dataset but ended up getting the whole Attorney column populated by the first name in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution (using @akrun's logic):

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", 
                   lapply(split(dataset, cumsum(!(grepl("\\d+", dataset$Attorney)))),
                                function(x){
                                  non_att_cols <- names(x)[names(x) != "Attorney"]
                                  y <- data.frame(na.omit(x[,non_att_cols]))
                                  y$Attorney <- x$Attorney[1]
                                  return(y[,c("Attorney", non_att_cols)])
                                }
                              )
                    ),
           row.names = NULL
          )
```